# Is this assignment correct?

Tags: javascript

In some js library I found this code snippet:

```
var start, end, sel, scrollPos, subst;

[start, end, scrollPos, sel] = getSelection();
```

Imo this is not valid assignment but code seems to be working. Can you help?

**EDIT:**

longer version:

```
...
var start, end, sel, scrollPos, subst;
        if (typeof(document["selection"]) != "undefined") {
            sel = document.selection.createRange().text;
        } else if (typeof(textarea["setSelectionRange"]) != "undefined") {
            [start, end, scrollPos, sel] = getSelection();
        }
...
```

Comment: is this just an example or is it exactly the code you've seen?

Comment: It is almoast exactly what I have here. It is part of some markdown toolbar extension.

Comment: This looks very similar to Pythons variable unpacking mechanism. The idea is that a list or tuple is unpacked linearly on the variables. This is often used to allow functions to return multiple values. I haven't heard that it is also available for JS.

Comment: I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working here: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. More context is needed. Possibly what you are looking at isn't JS.

Comment: Is this a firefox extension or something ? Looks to me like browser dependent code.

Comment: In Chromium this seems to work: `start, end, scrollPos, sel = getSelection()`

Comment: @j08691 I have same error in my netbeans ide. But Im not sure it is trustworthy in this case...

Comment: @Constantinius this is not the same as `[start, end, scrollPos, sel] = getSelection()` you're only assigning `getSelection()` to `sel`

Comment: @aduch: You are right.. I rest my case.

Comment: @Bergi Your overview is always stunning. I couldnt find it there ;) Perhaps wrong keywords :)

Comment: @Windkiller: Nah, I was searching for "destructuring assignment" to find a matching duplicate - you of course couldn't know that term…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a JS 1.7 feature called ["Destructuring Assignment"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Destructuring_assignment_(Merge_into_own_page.2Fsection))

> Destructuring assignment makes it possible to extract data from arrays or objects using a syntax that mirrors the construction of array and object literals.
>
> The object and array literal expressions provide an easy way to create ad-hoc packages of data. Once you've created these packages of data, you can use them any way you want to. You can even return them from functions.
>
> One particularly useful thing you can do with destructuring assignment is to read an entire structure in a single statement, although there are a number of interesting things you can do with them, as shown in the section full of examples that follows.
>
> This capability is similar to features present in languages such as Perl and Python.

...farther down the page:

> You can use destructuring assignment, for example, to swap values:
>
> ```
> var a = 1;
> var b = 3;
> [a, b] = [b, a];
> ```

As far as using the feature, it appears to only be supported by Mozilla Firefox, which means it's perfectly acceptable to use it so long as you're only supporting that browser. Browser plugins, for example, can be written to take advantage of this feature.