# Define an array with first element empty in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I saw there is an array was define as [, el1, el2], I never seen this way to define an array. If I define like this way, is means the first element is undefine?

```
const targetItems = [1, 2, 3, a, b, c].map( items=>{  
    const matches = itmes.match([a-z])
    const [, targetItems , remainItems] = matches
})
```

In this case, matches should be`[a, b, c]`, but what the final array should look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfamiliar use of square brackets during multiple variable declaration in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841820) and [Multiple assignment in javascript? What does \[a,b,c\] = \[1, 2, 3\]; mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986348) and [Syntax - what does square brackets around a variable declaration mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287635) and [Is this assignment correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175603) and [Square brackets around variable name (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929776)

Comment: adiga's probably right, although the last sentence in the question asks something else. It's a bit unclear, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is not an array declaration. This code:

```
 const [, targetItems , remainItems] = matches
```

Is equivalent to:

```
 const targetItems = matches[1]
 const remainItems = matches[2]
```

You're basically create two variables binding them to the value of the second and third element in the array. The comma is used so you can skip the element you're not interested. You can also use the spread syntax, so for example:

```
const [, x, , y, ...end] = ['a','b','c','d','e', 'f']

console.log(x) // "b"
console.log(y) // "d"
console.log(end) // ["e", "f"]
```

Said that, you can definitely also create arrays with empty slots:

```
const arr = [, 10];
```

> In this case, matches should be[a, b, c], but what the final array should look like?

In the code you posted there is no `return` for the array function (that use brackets so the statement is needed) therefore the array would be mapped to `undefined` for each element.

**Update**

```
const matches = itmes.match([a-z])
```

Assuming `itmes` is a typo for `items`, I would also assume that `items.match([a-z])` is actually `items.match(/[a-z]/)` since it wouldn't make sense otherwise – [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) takes a regexp as argument, even with type coercion it would make less sense the code comparing to a regexp typo.

However, even in that case the code won't work, since `match` would returns just one element, makes the whole destructuring useless – the only element returned is the one discarded. Plus, it would returns only one letter.

I believe the original code would be slightly different (e.g. having a global flag for the regexp, and / or some quantifiers, such "+"); so it's hard to figure out what would be the end results from the code provided.

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
const [, targetItems, remainItems] = matches
```

does not create (or "define") an array. It [*destructures*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) an array into individual variables (well, constants in this case). It's equivalent to:

```
const targetItems = matches[1];
const remainItems = matches[2];
```

Since there's no identifier name in the first position (after the `[` and before the `,`), the first entry (`matches[0]`) isn't stored anywhere.

This is called *array destructuring*. (JavaScript also has *object destructuring*.)

> ...what the final array should look like?

In that code, `targetItems` will be a six-entry array with all entries containing the value `undefined` because the `map` callback never returns a value, so calling it results in `undefined`. The callback should use `return` to return a value (or use the concise form of an arrow function with its implicit return, but it can't do that with statements in it).

As [ZER0 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54647882/157247), though, it is valid in modern JavaScript to leave out entries in an array initializer:

```js
const a = [ , "one", "two", , "four"];
console.log(a.length); // 5
console.log(a[0]);     // undefined
console.log(0 in a);   // false (because there's no entry at all)
console.log(a[1])      // "one"
console.log(1 in a);   // true
```

That's not what the code in the question is doing, but one of the great things about destructuring is that its syntax is that array destructuring syntax is **exactly** the same as array initializer ("literal") syntax, and object destructuring syntax is **exactly** the same as object initializer ("literal") syntax. It's just that when it's on the right-hand side of an assignment (or in a parameter list), it's destructuring an existing array/object rather than creating one.

---

This line is highly suspect:

```
const matches = itmes.match([a-z])
```

It expects there to be two in-scope identifiers, `a` and `z`, and then it subtracts `z` from `a` and uses the resulting value to create an array, then passes that array into `match` on `itmes` (sic). I assume that line's gotten garbled at some point...